# SPARQL query with turtle

Tags: sparql

i'm pretty new in SPARQL. Querying the linked data is an interesting concept. I have followed tutorials to comprehend it. Now, i'm using the data of European Comission as experiment model. (http://linkedpolitics.ops.few.vu.nl/home)

Now, i want to search amount of seats per country. This query here below gives what i want.

```
PREFIX lpv: <http://purl.org/linkedpolitics/vocabulary/> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

# count seats per country
SELECT ?country (COUNT(DISTINCT ?members) AS ?c)
WHERE {
   ?members lpv:countryOfRepresentation ?cOR .
   ?cOR rdfs:label ?country .
} GROUP BY ?cOR
```

Well, i thought that it should work, but what i get is the next

```
  ?country        ?c
1           "70"^^xsd:integer
2           "126"^^xsd:integer
3           "49"^^xsd:integer
4           "20"^^xsd:integer
```

The country column appears blank. Now when i adapt the query to

```
SELECT ?cOR (COUNT(DISTINCT ?members) AS ?c)
```

I get

```
         ?cOR              ?c
1   lp:EUCountry_AT     "70"^^xsd:integer
2   lp:EUCountry_BE     "126"^^xsd:integer
3   lp:EUCountry_BG     "49"^^xsd:integer
4   lp:EUCountry_CY     "20"^^xsd:integer
```

These results are URI (like the first one leads to http://linkedpolitics.ops.few.vu.nl/browse/list_resource?r=http%3A//purl.org/linkedpolitics/EUCountry_AT )

When you click on that, you can clearly see rdfs:label pointing to "Austria". But that doesn't appear at the first query result.

My question is, why does `?cOR rdfs:label ?country` give a blank result ? 
Is that caused by that "sameAs" thing ? And how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, your query isn't legal SPARQL.  You can't put a variable in the SELECT part when you're grouping by if that variable isn't one of the variables that you're grouping on.  You can check your query at [sparql.org's query validator](http://sparql.org/validate/query), which will tell you:

> Non-group key variable in SELECT: ?country

You could include ?country in your group by:

```sql
SELECT ?country (COUNT(DISTINCT ?members) AS ?c)
WHERE { ... }
GROUP BY ?cOR ?country
```

The problem with the latter is that there may be different values for the label.  E.g., you might "countryName"@en (a language tagged string) and "countryName" (a plain string).

```
    country         c
1   Austria         "70"^^xsd:integer
2   "Austria"@en    "70"^^xsd:integer
3   Belgium         "126"^^xsd:integer
4   "Belgium"@en    "126"^^xsd:integer
...
```

A perhaps better option would be to *sample* the value of ?country:

```sql
SELECT (sample(?country) as ?country_) (COUNT(DISTINCT ?members) AS ?c)
WHERE { ... }
GROUP BY ?cOR
```

```
    country_        c
1   "Austria"@en    "70"^^xsd:integer
2   "Belgium"@en    "126"^^xsd:integer
3   "Bulgaria"@en   "49"^^xsd:integer
```

Another alternative would be to filter the country labels to a given language.  E.g.,

```
SELECT ?country (COUNT(DISTINCT ?members) AS ?c)
WHERE { ...
  filter langMatches(lang(?country),"en")
}
GROUP BY ?cOR ?country
```

This seems to work for your query, but if a country had more than one English label, you'd still have the "duplicated results" issue that happened in the first candidate solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It has shown me some insights about my query. After reading your answer, i simply replaced the `?cOR` in the GROUP BY clause into `?country` and now, the country column displays the labels. I have to be careful with this kind of query language since it's treatening the data way differently than what the SQL family does. Still, what does `sample(...)` do ? [The specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggSample) isn't clear about that.

Comment: Actually, this is pretty much exactly the way that sql would handle this one, too. When you group by some variable, you end up with a set of values for each of the other variables per group. Sample samples from that set, and just returns one of them.

Comment: Eg,if you had four [name, age] result rows in the un grouped query, (John, 25), (Mary, 25), (Tom,  56), (Tim, 56) and grouped by age, you'd get ({John, mary}, 26) ({tom, tim}, 56), just like sql.